# How I can get to work a foo.local mDNS link between an ESP32 Server and an ESP32 Client?

Tags: server, arduino, client, esp32

I am trying to access `http:///myServerName.local/` link through a client running on ESP32 after I establish the mDNS on the server running on another ESP32.

I tried implementing an HTTP request with the previous link, but it won't seem to work. I also tried just to access the link from my browser but that won't work either.

```
  Client Code:


  HTTPClient http;

  Serial.print("[HTTP] begin... \n");

  http.begin("http://myServerName.local/"); //HTTP

  Serial.print("[HTTP GET... \n");

  int httpCode = http.GET();
  ...


 Server Code:

 void advertiseServices(const char* myName)
 {
   if(MDNS.begin(myName))
   {
     Serial.println(F("mDNS responder started."));
     Serial.print(F("I am: "));
     Serial.println(myName);

     //Add service to MDNS-SD
     MDNS.addService("http", "tcp", 80);
   }
   else
   {
     while(1)
     {
       Serial.println(F("Error setting up MDNS responder"));
       delay(1000);
     }
   }
 }


 void setup(void) 
 {
   //Activarea serviciilor prin care putem lua legatura cu device-urile in functie de numele lor
   advertiseServices("myServerName");
   ...
 }
```

The only thing I got so far was `-1` for `httpCode` and nothing else.

Comment: Can you show the main `loop()` in your server code? I suspect that the hostname actually is being advertised - but that the server code is hanging somewhere.

Comment: Sure, but is nothing much...  `void loop(void) 
{
  server.handleClient();
  
  delay(500);
}` If it helps.